# Transitioning from C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

Any suggestions on how I should approach this?  Thanks.

Comment: With revulsion and horror? :)

Comment: VS code formatting for VB.NET is actually kinda nice, but the lack of anonymous delegates kills me.

Comment: Real question:  Are you just going to start writing new code in VB.NET or are you converting a whole codebase from C# to VB.NET?

Comment: @Janie: the only reason I can think of is being in need of a job, and some vacancy being for VB.NET

Comment: @Larsenal - VB.NET has those now (though they can only be an expression, not a block of statements).

Comment: I've had to do it frequently.  Could be a new job in a VB shop, maybe the OP just inherited an acquired product that was written in VB.net.  Given the choice, I prefer C# (vb's verbose), but vb.net is a perfectly good language all the same.

Comment: It is for a new gig.  There is no conversion, it is a VB.NET shop and my C# skills have no place there :(

Comment: @CriosR - if you can call yourself an expert C# programmer, you'll be a an expert in VB in no time flat.  Don't sweat it - your new gig will work out better than you think.

Comment: The real question is how can you transition the rest of them from VB.NET to C#.  Be like a virus!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to do this often - and my biggest hang-up is the semi-colon.  Never fails that my first few days of writing VB after a longer stint of C# coding, the VB compiler is always barking at me for putting a semi-colon on every line of VB code.

Other than that, it shouldn't be too painful.  If you're fluent in C#, moving to VB might be stressful for the first few days, but after that you should be smooth sailing.

Code converter tools come in handy to help you remember/learn/re-learn all of those odd syntax differences that you forget easily.  The one I normally turn to first is http://converter.telerik.com/ - and if that won't do the trick, a quick google search for code converters will turn up a handful of other good ones.

Another pain point that I've had in the past too is Snippets.  Snippets in C# rock - but in VB rock a bit less.  Get to know the differences between those and life will be much easier.  (Come on VB team - get that enter key working like the C# snippet team has it...)

Comment: Heh, absolutely.  My pinkie finger is so trained to hit the semi-colon I accidentally end many sentences with one rather than a period.

Comment: yep - that's exactly my problem too;

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this [VB to C# Comparison](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html) chart for some of the syntax and keyword differences.

Answer (score 3):

A good [C# to VB.NET converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) will help.

Comment: Don't use these!  I've had to fix more problems generated by these than I like to remember.  Use your brain instead.

Comment: @Greg - converters are your friend as long as you use the converter to learn the differences in the syntax, not to write all your code for you.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from revulsion and horror I recommend (from experience - ugh) to just start.  Build a simple app.  The magic is in the experience.  It doesn't make sense until you have spent lots of time trying to figure out why something doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I went the other way (VB to C#) and found the syntax to be so similar that the transition was painless.  I can now pretty much program in either platform – thanks a lot to the IDE intellisense.

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of the "With" statement!  One of my favorite parts of VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as difficult as it seems at first.  Took me about a month from going strictly C++\C# to VB to get comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with programing you should just have to learn the syntax...why would anyone want to go from C# to VB? who knows  :)

Answer (score 0):

My first question would be 'Why?'. I'd like to think that you can pretty much get the same thing done with either C# or VB.Net. Given that it's managed code, why not just leave them as they are?

Let's just assume you have your reasons :)

1) There are a couple of tools that will do this (see http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ for a sample).
2) The other option is to manually convert the code, compile, fix errors, and repeat. Painful.

Comment: Consultants & contract developers often have the language choices made for them by their clients.  In those situations, being fluent in both VB & C# will take you far...

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty straight-forward thing, actually.  VB.Net is a perfectly good (if, imo, verbose) language with most of the expressiveness you've grown accustomed to in C#.  Just be aware that certain specific keywords are different and that you've got a different background culture and you'll do fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a tool like [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) from DevExpress (no affiliation).  The short-cut keys for any operation are the same for both languages and will produce the correct output for the language.

For example: key combo "mv" yields:

In C#

```
public void MethodName ()
{

}
```

In VB

```
Public Sub MethodName()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [XML literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364068(VS.80).aspx#vb9overview_topic6) and marvel how resentful fellow C# programmers suddenly are.

Answer (score 0):

There were some useful articles in Visual Studio magazine back in Jan 2008.

- [What C# developers should know about VB](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/columns/article.aspx?editorialsid=2894)
- And for completeness: [what VB developers should know about C#](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/12/01/what-vb-devs-should-know-about-c.aspx)